# Writing a generic method and the compiler expects T to be a known type

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a generic extension method.  The compiler does not accept my generic parameter.  The compiler message is

The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Can someone point out what I should do differently?  Here is the code

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensionMethods
{
  public static Stack<T> ToStack(this IEnumerable<T> source)
  {
     var reversed = source.Reverse();
     if(source is ICollection<T>)
        return new Stack<T>(reversed);

     var returnStack = new Stack<T>(reversed.Count);
     foreach (T item in reversed)
        returnStack.Push(item);

     return returnStack;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your entire method body can just be `return new Stack<T>(source.Reverse());`.  There's no need to manually insert each item.

Comment: I will try that.  I put the conditional in there because source is IEnumerable and the documentation on Stack<T>(param) says param is an ICollection.

Comment: @philologon No, the parameter is an `IEnumerable<T>`, not an `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate.  None of them showed up as I was composing the question.  (I did look.)

Comment: The documentation /does/ say IEnumerable.  I was just reading it too fast or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method signature needs a type parameter:

```
public static Stack<T> ToStack<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
```

As a sidenote, this won't compile once you fix that. You need to call the `Count()` method on `IEnumerable`:

```
var returnStack = new Stack<T>(reversed.Count());
```

Also as @Servy points out in the comments, the check for whether this is an `ICollection<T>` isn't necessary; there's a `Stack<T>` constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`. You could use:

```
new Stack<T>(source.Reverse());
```

instead.

Comment: Okay.  For some reason when I read the documentation I thought it only accepted ICollections.  I must have been reading it too fast (as I am wont to do when I am working).